# "missing ; before statement" error

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the number which is basically 116 into a cell on Google sheets with the following code, however I get the `missing ; before statement` error:

```
var copper = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.diviscan.io/masternodes");


  var copperObject = JSON.parse(copper);
  Logger.log(copperObject.layers['copper'].getContentText());

  var fact3 = copperObject.layers['copper'].getContentText());
  var sheet3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet3.getRange(2,5).setValue([fact3]);
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra closing parens on this line:

```
var fact3 = copperObject.layers['copper'].getContentText());
```